# 18.04.1 LTS - Mic Not Working

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, microphone

Sorry to add to the wildfire, but I'm on a fresh setup of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and my microphone isn't working.

Microphone in question: Boya BY-M1

My Sound -> Input settings look like this:

[image]

Note that there is activity in the orange monitor, however when I try to record in Audacity there isn't actually sound. Also the activity doesn't respond when I clap or tap the mic.

I've also fiddled a little with `alsamixer`. My settings for that look like:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to boot from usb Ubuntu 18.10 and this make same problem? Otherwise it could be a driver/kernel problem.

Comment: Not yet but I'll try and report back tomorrow. Thanks for the idea :)